# Gnome Fallback with Compiz - maximized windows lose focus

Tags: 13.04, compiz, gnome-classic, docky

I use gnome-fallback with compiz and docky. However, when I open an application that starts maximized, such as firefox, the window will lose focus if I click anywhere on the window decoration. Hovering over the window buttons does not make them change colors as it usually would. This problem arose after changing the window theme using gnome-tweak-tool. I remember having this problem before, and I fixed it by purging and reinstalling compiz. I tried this again, but to no avail. If I minimize the window using docky and then open the window again, the problem is gone. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

UPDATE:

I logged in to Gnome Fallback using metacity. I opened a terminal and ran `compiz --replace`, and the last two lines caught my eye:

```
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
```

With this additional information, does anybody know what's going on?

UPDATE:

I tried changing the theme using Ubuntu Tweak rather than the Gnome Tweak Tool. This did not resolve the problem.

UPDATE:

I ran compiz in debug mode. Here is the output:

```
josh@josh-laptop:~$     compiz --replace --debug --verbose
compiz (core) - Warn: Unknown option '--verbose'

compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load core from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libcore.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libcore.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load core from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libcore.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /usr/lib/    compiz/libcore.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: core
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 1721
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 1280 height: 714 border: 0, sibling: 0x0
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 1735
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 1280 height: 714 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00090
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 1801
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0009c
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 554 y: 290 width: 722 height: 421 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 1867
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0009f
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 722 height: 421 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e0009c
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load ccp from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libccp.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libccp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load ccp from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libccp.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libccp.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin ccp from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libccp.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : Default
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load composite from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libcomposite.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libcomposite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load composite from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libcomposite.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libcomposite.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin composite from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libcomposite.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load opengl from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libopengl.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libopengl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load opengl from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libopengl.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libopengl.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin opengl from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libopengl.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgjpeg
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load imgjpeg from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libimgjpeg.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libimgjpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load imgjpeg from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libimgjpeg.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libimgjpeg.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin imgjpeg from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libimgjpeg.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgjpeg
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: imgjpeg
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load decor from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libdecor.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libdecor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load decor from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libdecor.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libdecor.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin decor from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libdecor.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load imgpng from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libimgpng.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libimgpng.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load imgpng from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libimgpng.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libimgpng.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin imgpng from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libimgpng.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load gnomecompat from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libgnomecompat.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libgnomecompat.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load gnomecompat from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libgnomecompat.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libgnomecompat.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin gnomecompat from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libgnomecompat.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: titleinfo
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load titleinfo from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libtitleinfo.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libtitleinfo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load titleinfo from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libtitleinfo.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libtitleinfo.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin titleinfo from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libtitleinfo.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: titleinfo
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: titleinfo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load vpswitch from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libvpswitch.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libvpswitch.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load vpswitch from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libvpswitch.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libvpswitch.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin vpswitch from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libvpswitch.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load place from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libplace.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libplace.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load place from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libplace.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libplace.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin place from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libplace.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load snap from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libsnap.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libsnap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load snap from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libsnap.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libsnap.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin snap from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libsnap.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: text
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load text from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libtext.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libtext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load text from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libtext.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libtext.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin text from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libtext.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: text
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: text
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load grid from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libgrid.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libgrid.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load grid from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libgrid.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libgrid.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin grid from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libgrid.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load resize from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libresize.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libresize.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load resize from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libresize.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libresize.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin resize from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libresize.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgsvg
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load imgsvg from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libimgsvg.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libimgsvg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load imgsvg from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libimgsvg.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libimgsvg.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin imgsvg from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libimgsvg.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgsvg
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: imgsvg
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load move from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libmove.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libmove.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load move from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libmove.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libmove.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin move from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libmove.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin:     compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load     compiztoolbox from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/lib    compiztoolbox.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/lib    compiztoolbox.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load     compiztoolbox from: /usr/lib/    compiz/lib    compiztoolbox.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/lib    compiztoolbox.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin     compiztoolbox from: /usr/lib/    compiz/lib    compiztoolbox.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin:     compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin:     compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load regex from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libregex.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libregex.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load regex from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libregex.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libregex.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin regex from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libregex.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load mousepoll from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libmousepoll.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libmousepoll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load mousepoll from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libmousepoll.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libmousepoll.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin mousepoll from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libmousepoll.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: thumbnail
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load thumbnail from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libthumbnail.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libthumbnail.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load thumbnail from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libthumbnail.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libthumbnail.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin thumbnail from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libthumbnail.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: thumbnail
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: thumbnail
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load animation from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libanimation.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libanimation.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load animation from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libanimation.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libanimation.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin animation from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libanimation.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load workarounds from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libworkarounds.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libworkarounds.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load workarounds from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libworkarounds.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libworkarounds.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin workarounds from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libworkarounds.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load session from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libsession.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libsession.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load session from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libsession.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libsession.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin session from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libsession.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: staticswitcher
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load staticswitcher from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libstaticswitcher.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libstaticswitcher.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load staticswitcher from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libstaticswitcher.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libstaticswitcher.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin staticswitcher from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libstaticswitcher.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: staticswitcher
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: staticswitcher
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load expo from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libexpo.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libexpo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load expo from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libexpo.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libexpo.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin expo from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libexpo.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ring
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load ring from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libring.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load ring from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libring.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libring.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin ring from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libring.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ring
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: ring
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load fade from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libfade.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libfade.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load fade from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libfade.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libfade.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin fade from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libfade.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: addhelper
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load addhelper from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libaddhelper.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libaddhelper.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load addhelper from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libaddhelper.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libaddhelper.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin addhelper from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libaddhelper.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: addhelper
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: addhelper
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load scale from: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libscale.so
compiz (core) - Debug: dlopen failed: /home/josh/.    compiz-1/plugins/libscale.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
compiz (core) - Debug: Trying to load scale from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libscale.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Opened library: /usr/lib/    compiz/libscale.so
compiz (core) - Debug: Loaded plugin scale from: /usr/lib/    compiz/libscale.so
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Debug: Started plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e00090
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e00093
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e00096
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 1721
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 1280 height: 714 border: 0, sibling: 0x0
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 1735
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 1280 height: 714 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00090
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e0009c
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4369
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00096
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 452 y: 738 width: 1280 height: 190 border: -986896, sibling: 0xff6e6e6e
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 1801
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0009c
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 554 y: 290 width: 722 height: 421 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e0009f
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 1867
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0009f
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 722 height: 421 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e0009c
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4427
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0009f
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: -2 y: -1 width: 726 height: 448 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e0009c
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4461
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 1280 height: 776 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00090
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4508
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0009f
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: -4 y: -26 width: 726 height: 448 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e0009c
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4666
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: -4 y: -26 width: 726 height: 448 border: 0, sibling: 0x0
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4690
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 726 height: 448 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4766
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00142
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 550 y: 240 width: 726 height: 448 border: 128, sibling: 0x30
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4790
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00142
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 552 y: 265 width: 726 height: 448 border: 128, sibling: 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: stacks are out of sync
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4369
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00096
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 452 y: 738 width: 1280 height: 190 border: -986896, sibling: 0xff6e6e6e
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 5070
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00096
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 610 width: 1280 height: 190 border: -986896, sibling: 0xff6e6e6e
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e00139
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4461
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 1280 height: 776 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00090
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4666
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: -4 y: -26 width: 726 height: 448 border: 0, sibling: 0x0
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e00140
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4690
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 24 width: 726 height: 448 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e00142
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4766
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00142
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 550 y: 240 width: 726 height: 448 border: 128, sibling: 0x30
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e00144
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 4790
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00142
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 552 y: 265 width: 726 height: 448 border: 128, sibling: 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: refusing to manage window 0x3e00154
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 5070
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00096
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 0 y: 610 width: 1280 height: 190 border: -986896, sibling: 0xff6e6e6e
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 5834
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: -7 y: 24 width: 740 height: 455 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 5869
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00142
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 545 y: 265 width: 740 height: 455 border: 128, sibling: 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 5834
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: -7 y: 24 width: 740 height: 455 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00099
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 5869
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e00142
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: 545 y: 265 width: 740 height: 455 border: 128, sibling: 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: pending request:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 6908
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: -7 y: 24 width: 740 height: 455 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00142
compiz (core) - Debug: received event:
compiz (core) - Debug: - event serial: 6908
compiz (core) - Debug: - event window 0x3e0013e
compiz (core) - Debug: - x: -7 y: 24 width: 740 height: 455 border: 0, sibling: 0x3e00142
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing a later version of Compiz from the .deb files available on [this page](https://launchpad.net/~mar-kolya/+archive/mate/+build/4944105). The page says that it's for Compiz 0.9.10. Running `compiz --version` outputs `0.9.11`, but hey, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you use the Ambiance theme.

Try the Mediterranean theme, watch the bug disappear magically.

It seems there is some issues in Compiz or the Ambiance theme (at least the themes that come from the Ubuntu Theme) that causes it.

This is a frustrating issue really.

I had to use the Mediterranean theme to get around it.

or else, you can download the latest Compiz Code which has a fix, compile it yourself/create a deb and install it. There are some instructions in some forums for compiling the same. Google for the same.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using Ambiance, I'm using the Elegant Gnome window theme with the Elementaryish gtk+ theme. However, it sounds like this might just be the solution to my problem.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the page you speak of. Are you able to provide a link? If so, please do. Thanks!

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1158267/comments/40

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be you better re-install compiz settings manager ,

I mean open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then restart your system.

Comment: I have done this many times. However, I will try again.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'm afraid it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install will not work. For some people it may have worked if they have tinkered with versions in the apt-sources.

Follow steps below.

This involves downgrading a step back,
But I have tested this and it does work.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1158267/comments/40

The comment number 40 is what you would like to do.

this will install build tools and other stuff necessary to build re-compile and create package

Godd Luck

Comment: Downgrading is not the entire system , but the version of COmpiz. Above step downgrades only the version of Compiz.